# SVM classification - normalization in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, normalization, libsvm

I want to work with `SVM` classification. How is it possible to normalize (or scale) the features per column in my dataset before i use the `SVM` model?

```
train <- read.csv("train.csv")
test <- read.csv("test.csv")

svm.fit=svm(as.factor(type)~ ., data=train, core="libsvm",kernel="linear",cross=10, probability=TRUE)
```

Comment: Do you have some example data you can provide?  Not sure what type of data you have (e.g., discrete, continuous)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `scale` function in an `sapply`:

```
scaleddf <- as.data.frame(sapply(train, function(i) if(is.numeric(i)) scale(i) else i))
```

If your data contains variables with `NaN` values or with 0 variance, you could first process and subset the original dataset before using the function above.

```
# get a vector of variables to drop
dropVars <- sapply(train, function(i) {
              if((is.numeric(i) & !any(is.nan(i)) & sd(i) > 0) | is.factor(i) | is.character(i)) TRUE
              else FALSE
              }
# subset test dropping columns that don't fit the criteria
smallerdf <- test[, dropVars]
```

Then apply the original `sapply` function above to smallerdf

Comment: It is giving me this error. `Error in model.frame.default(formula, data) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'lice_id')` i have tried it with `na.action=na.omit` but that doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: @Mahsolid I am not sure what the problem is, but it sounds like one of the variables has missing values. You may find a better answer by looking running this error message in a search engine and SO together with the function you are using. You might also take a look at your variables to see if you find missing values. If neither of these turns up an answer, it may be worth while to post a new question on SO so that those who use this function more often can take a look.